# application.Children is an empty list while using SAP GUI with VBScript:

Tags: vbscript, autodesk, sap-gui

`The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index.`

I get the above error on line number of 3 of the following code:

```
Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = application.Children(0)
```

How to check size of application.Children?

Comment: The syntax for returning the number of elements in an array is `UBound(ArrayName[,dimension])`. The dimension is only needed when dealing with multidimensional arrays. I know nothing about SAP, but when I see `Children` I suspect there may also be a `Children.Count()` function, but that is speculation on my part.

Comment: You should probably also check if  `SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine` actually returns something (`If application Is Nothing` ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the SAP (SAP Logon/SAP GUI) are not open.

But if you want, try:

```
ChildCount = application.Children.Count
```