# VBA error 438 - object does not accept property or method

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

can you help with code and message

> error 438 - object does not accept property or method

Code follows. The error is at 6th line (`Set Connection = Application.Children(0)`).

```
If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Appl = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = Appl.Openconnection("[PRD] ECC Production", True)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
```

My knowledge is basic, what I'm trying to do, have a code that click access the SAP connection path:

1. workspace
2. Brazil
3. on the PRD connection [image]

Comment: Your "Application" object might not *HAVE* any children.  Hence the runtime error.  Look here for the solution:  [application.Children is an empty list while using SAP GUI with VBScript:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365071/application-children-is-an-empty-list-while-using-sap-gui-with-vbscript)

Comment: You don't use the right variable: you are using `Application` although you named it `Appl`. If your question is solved this way, you may delete your question (otherwise your question would be closed because of "question due to typo").